# cmd can find curl but where does curl stores its path on windows

Tags: windows

I can type curl in cmd it finds it

but looking at environment variable path, it isn't stored there, so whete is it stored so that cmd can access it ? I thought cmd could only read path environment variable?

Comment: type `where curl` to see

Comment: @phuclv thanks it works. So cmd can read something else than path?

Comment: no, it still looks inside the path, just like what `where` does. While running commands the shell does also [look at some other places](https://superuser.com/q/1351532/241386). However if `where` sees a binary then it must be in the path